# Static menu inside my children components with routing

Tags: angular, angular-router, ng-template, ng-content, ng-container

I want my static menu to be inside my both children components, how to achieve that?

I tried with `ng-template`, `ng-content`, `ng-container`, `ngTemplateOutlet` directives but I didn't find an example that works with `router-outlet`.
[image]

I don't want to duplicate my menu in children.

[Here is start with stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ojgulj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common component to be reused:

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Place the menu related css and html in the component's css and html file.

Once you done that, you can place it in your child component's html like:

**Child 1**

```
<div>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <p>Child 1</p>
</div>
```

**Child 2**

```
<div>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <p>Child 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok it was not what I was looking for, but I think there is no other way... That's what I finally doing too.